# fancybox onload

Tags: fancybox, onload-event

I would like to load my fancybiox iframe when the page is loaded:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){


    $("a.various2").fancybox({ 
        padding: 0,
        margin: 0,
        width: 400,
        height: 350,
        autoSize    : true,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none'
    });

                    });
        </script>

</head>

<body>
<a class="various2" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="nlpumc.html">Iframe</a>
```

This script works by clicking on the link. But how does it work with document ready? I testet:

```
$("a.various2").fancybox.open({
```

That's not correct?

Thank you!

Comment: check http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#useful No.12

Answer (score 0):

**Here's the HTML...**

```
<a class="fancybox" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_s.jpg" alt=""/></a>

<a class="fancybox" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_s.jpg" alt=""/></a>
```

**And here's the JS...**

```
// Activate fancyBox
$(".fancybox")
    .attr('rel', 'gallery')
    .fancybox({
        padding : 0
    });


// Launch fancyBox on first element
$(".fancybox").eq(0).trigger('click');
```

**And now the JSFiddle...**

Click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Py2RA/).

Works like a charm!